# WindowsでAppiumを使用してAndroid携帯を自動で動作させる方法

Tags: javascript, java, ruby, windows, appium

Android携帯で自作アプリを自動で動作させる為にAppium環境を構築致しました。
自動で動作させるためのスクリプトはJavaやJavaScript,Ruby等で可能とあり参考サイトをあちこち回った結果、Rubyでapkインストール、アプリ起動、タップまではできました。

Wi-Fiの設定一覧画面を表示する場面があり、一覧から特定の名前のWi-Fiを選択したいのですが、リストからアイテムを取り出す方法と特定のものを選択する方法がわかりません。
Rubyでリストの読み込み、リストアイテム（テキスト）を取り出す方法、選択する方法を教えて下さい。

そもそもその操作がRubyで出来ない場合はどの言語で可能かも教えてくださると幸いです。